# lxde lxterminal cross-compile failure

Tags: openwrt, xorg

I am using xorg/lxde on a custom openwrt (x86_64) distribution. Lxterminal (0.3.0, 0.3.2) used to compile on a previous (r50108) version, but not on openwrt trunk.

It hangs in a repetive loop creating /po files. Ie;

```
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/rossb/OpenWrt/x86_64/r8210/trunk/build_dir/target-x86_64_glibc/lxterminal-0.3.2/po'
cd .. \
&& CONFIG_FILES=po/Makefile.in CONFIG_HEADERS= CONFIG_LINKS= \
   /bin/sh ./config.status
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing default-1 commands
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/rossb/OpenWrt/x86_64/r8210/trunk/build_dir/target-x86_64_glibc/lxterminal-0.3.2/po'
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/rossb/OpenWrt/x86_64/r8210/trunk/build_dir/target-x86_64_glibc/lxterminal-0.3.2/po'
cd .. \
&& CONFIG_FILES=po/Makefile.in CONFIG_HEADERS= CONFIG_LINKS= \
   /bin/sh ./config.status
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing default-1 commands
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/rossb/OpenWrt/x86_64/r8210/trunk/build_dir/target-x86_64_glibc/lxterminal-0.3.2/po'
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/rossb/OpenWrt/x86_64/r8210/trunk/build_dir/target-x86_64_glibc/lxterminal-0.3.2/po'
cd .. \
&& CONFIG_FILES=po/Makefile.in CONFIG_HEADERS= CONFIG_LINKS= \
   /bin/sh ./config.status
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing default-1 commands
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/rossb/OpenWrt/x86_64/r8210/trunk/build_dir/target-x86_64_glibc/lxterminal-0.3.2/po'
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/rossb/OpenWrt/x86_64/r8210/trunk/build_dir/target-x86_64_glibc/lxterminal-0.3.2/po'
```

..endlessly, as if some done stamp is missing.

I have no clue how to debug this.

Here is config.log: https://www.rossco.org/Downloads/OpenWrt/config.log

Anybody have any insight?

Thanks;
Bill

Comment: After my complete distribution compile, lxterminal successfully compiles. So, it is a matter of missing dependency('s). How to determine what was missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the config.log, it says

```
conftest.c:26:37: fatal error: CoreFoundation/CFLocale.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Which means your package has dependency on the package hosting "CFLocale.h" header file.